# Calculating variability index for strings of numbers in R

Tags: r, loops

I have many thousands of strings of numbers in a vector, with each number representing a tone realization (fall, rise, fall-rise, etc.) in units of speech. To illustrate:

```
Tones <- c("2222", "1411", "112", "815", "21111522")
```

What I'd like to get for each string is a variability index, by

1. comparing each number in the string to the immediately next,
2. storing a "1" if that next number is different than the preceding
   number,
3. storing a "0" if that next number equals the preceding number,
4. adding up these stored values and
5. dividing them by the total number of number pairs.

For example, for "2222", the variability index would be 0 because the first number in the string equals the second number, the second equals the third, and the third equals the last; thus the variability index would be (0+0+0)/3=0. For the string "1411" the index would be (1+1+0)/3=0.6666667 because "1" differs from "4", "4" differs from "1", and "1" equals "1".

I guess one will have to start by splitting the strings:

```
TonesSplit <- strsplit(Tones, split="")
```

which gives a list, then use `for` loops and `if` clauses to address the cells in the list slices. Just how to do it I don't know. I'd be very grateful for advice on how to program this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `base` one-liner R solution:

```
vapply(Tones,function(x) length(rle(charToRaw(x))$lengths)-1,1)/(nchar(Tones)-1)
#     2222      1411       112       815  21111522 
#0.0000000 0.6666667 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.4285714
```

Some explanation:

- with `charToRaw` I get for each string the raw byte content;
- with `rle` I get the number of sequences of repeating characters. The changes are just the number of sequences less one;
- with `vapply` I apply to each string the function;
- with `nchar` I get the number of characters of each string.

Comment: A pretty neat solution. Could you perhaps add a little explanation for the code's components?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
library(dplyr)

Tones <- c("2222", "1411", "112", "815", "21111522")

TonesSplit <- lapply(strsplit(Tones, split=""), as.numeric)

sapply(TonesSplit, function(x){
  sum(ifelse(x != dplyr::lag(x, 1), 1, 0), na.rm = T)/(length(x)-1)
})

[1] 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.4285714
```

In the `ifelse`, we use `dplyr::lag()` to compare each vector of split numbers with the vector [-1], therefore generating a new vector that starts with `NA` and then gives `0` or `1`, depending on the condition. We then sum this vector, ignoring the `NA`, and divide it by `length(x)-1`, which is the number of pairs.

---

A `microbenchmark` shows that the solution by @nicola is considerably faster:

```
microbenchmark(nicola = vapply(Tones,function(x) length(rle(charToRaw(x))$lengths)-1,1)/(nchar(Tones)-1),
               LAP = sapply(lapply(strsplit(Tones, split=""), as.numeric), function(x){
                 sum(ifelse(x != dplyr::lag(x, 1), 1, 0), na.rm = T)/(length(x)-1)
               }),
               unit = "ms")

Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 nicola 0.077654 0.0841960 0.1047870 0.0871830 0.0934405 1.684196   100   a
    LAP 0.109227 0.1194675 0.1482074 0.1230225 0.1281425 2.525868   100   a
```